# SQL Server - Get calander month begining and end

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've tried searching but cannot find anything.

I am trying to get the first and last date of the ***calander*** month.

So for example the calander month for January 2020 actually starts on December 30th 2019 and ends on February 2nd 2020. (Week 1 - 5)

```
|---------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|      Week number    |     From Date     |     To Date       |
|---------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|       Week 01       | December 30, 2019 | January 5, 2020   |
|---------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|       Week 05       | January 27, 2020  | February 2, 2020  |
|---------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
```

[Using this website to get week numbers](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2020)

Is this possible?

Many thanks.

Comment: The first and last date of a calendar _month_, by _week_ doesn't make intuitive sense to me. What is the output you're expecting from your sample data?

Comment: I believe OP is asking the wrong question here. They want the dates on the calendar as if you were looking at the calendar on a wall or in your outlook calendar. Ex. my calendar for January shows December 29, 2019 and February 1st. Although they aren't part of January, they are just "fillers" on the calendar.

Comment: Yes correct. I don't want the dates 1st Jan 2020 - 31st Jan 2020.

Instead I need the calander month so Dec 30th 2019 - Feb 2nd 2020

Comment: Just as an example if I run:
select DATEPART(week,'March 23 2020') that is 13.
In the link I added at the top week 13 is correct. But I need the start of that month so in this case it would be March 2, 2020 (Week 10) as the start.

Hope that makes a bit more sense?

Comment: I may need to use something like: SELECT WEEKOFYEAR("2019-12-30") - This brings me back Week 1 which would be correct as its Week 1 of 2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## If you are using MSSQL-2012 or onwards.

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME='29-JAN-2020'

SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, 2 - CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @DATE-DAY(@DATE)+1)=1 THEN 8 ELSE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @DATE-DAY(@DATE)+1) END, CAST( @DATE-DAY(@DATE)+1 AS DATE)) [MONTH_START_DATE], 
DATEADD(DAY, 8 - CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EOMONTH(@DATE))=1 THEN 8 ELSE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EOMONTH(@DATE)) END , CAST(EOMONTH(@DATE) AS DATE)) [MONTH_END_DATE];
```

### You can try on below link:-

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=9747ea25d0d0bc343be8dbcc90803303

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much

Comment: Just to add to this if I do December 1st 2019 it brings back the following - Month Start: 2019-12-02 (Correct) & Month end 2020-01-05 (incorrect). Month end should be 2019-12-29 - Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @Dereck  Dear check now with updated code.

`1-dec-2019` = last day of week means first day of that week is `25-nov-2019` which should be first day of month.
`31-dec-2019`= second day of week means `5-jan-2020` is last day of week which should be last day of month.
The link you refer you in question All weeks are starting on Monday and ending on Sunday.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this logic:

```
select convert(date, dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), getdate())) as month_first,
       dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(getdate(), -1)) as alternative_month_first,
       eomonth(getdate()) as month_last
```

Of course, you would use whatever date you wanted instead of `getdate()`.